# Bringing laptop without battery to the US

Tags: airports, airport-security, electronic-items

I own a laptop but without the battery (since I never used it, I gave it away). Since it is required to have a charged battery on some flights to the US, I was wondering how to bring my laptop to the US. Who should I contact to get an exemption?

Comment: Why do you need to have a charged battery on some flights to the US?  Is this an airline regulation?

Comment: @Karlson It's [officially required by the TSA](http://www.tsa.gov/press/releases/2014/07/06/enhanced-security-measures-certain-airports-overseas) on some flights.

Comment: @Karlson Since last year the US demands that all electronic gear should be able to turn on at security. This is to check that the devices are genuine.

Comment: Best I can figure that it applies to the flights from the Middle East.  A friend of mine had flown with a laptop with no battery with no issues.  If you don't have one and need to power it on take out the charger and request to plug it in.

Comment: @Karlson they do it [randomly]..

Answer (score 4):

There is not an "exemption" you can apply for, all you can do is take your power cord with the laptop and tell them that you only use the computer when plugged in.

TSA officers have the right to ask you to turn on an electronic device to prove it is a functional device. But not every device is checked, nor every flight, it is at the discretion of the TSA officers on duty when you arrive.

My experience is that they will allow you to use a wall outlet (they did for me after one long flight where my work needs exceeded my battery life)

Comment: It probably goes without saying, but make sure you have a US plug converter with you before you leave for the USA. Your European (or wherever) electrical plug won't fit in our outlets. I can just imagine someone arriving in the US, going through customs, rechecking their bag, going through security (for a connecting flight) and not being able to plug in their laptop.