# Laptop with no battery

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airport-security, electronic-items

I am traveling from the US to the UK and then to Portugal. Round trip. I have a laptop without a battery, so I am hesitant to bring it as carry-on in the plane because I had troubles already with a laptop not turning on through security.

Is there any problem with sending the laptop in the checked-in luggage? If they open my luggage and they find it, would that be a problem? Could they take it away?

Comment: Why do you carry a laptop without a battery?

Comment: The battery was damaged. I had to remove it. I ordered a battery online but I didn't get it on time for my upcoming trip.

Comment: You will definitely not be creating any danger by putting the notebook computer in the checked luggage, sans battery. Whether that breaks any rules I will let others answer. Do not bring the bad battery at all.

Comment: It's also perfectly logical that a laptop battery may simply be dead on arrival at a security gate... they know these things happen. No one is going to lose their laptop to the authorities cause it won't turn on. Just bring it with the power cord available. Not sure about the UK, but in the states is pretty uncommon for them to have you turn it on. Everyone has a device now... think about the extra hours it would take to validate each one is real.

Comment: My issue with getting through security in the US this last time was that I ran out of battery and didn't have the right plug. Even though I could get one right there, they ask me to go outside of security, charge it, and then bring it with battery again or I couldn't get through security. It was a mess..

Comment: @maplemale While it's comparatively uncommon to be asked, the official advice is that [you should not travel with electronics that you cannot turn on](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/terrorism-in-the-uk/10952671/Airport-security-you-wont-fly-to-the-US-if-your-mobile-phone-battery-is-dead.html), especially for flights to the US. If you are asked to demonstrate that the device works and you can't do so, they won't let you take it.

Comment: @ZachLipton Interesting... I stand corrected.

Comment: @maplemale your comment is perfectly reasonable and thus inapplicable to the TSA.

Comment: @emory Totally. lol Though... I haven't seen a TSA agent ask to turn a laptop on in years. I fly about 10 - 20 times a year. Maybe just lucky...

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [Bringing laptop without battery to the US](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/49842/12011).

Comment: I haven't been to Portugal,  but in 20+ US-UK round trips, no one has ever asked me to turn on my laptop.

Comment: I have done a fair amount of flights Europe to the US and last time it was the first time I was asked to turn my laptop on.

Answer (score 10):

There is no issue with traveling with a laptop without a battery. Just plug it in if you are asked to demonstrate that it is really working and it isn't a fake laptop. If I were you, I'd rather travel with it as a carry-on luggage to keep it with me. It is certainly safer. And if they have trouble with that, you can check it in as a fallback.

Comment: My only problem is that last time through security they didn't just let me plug it in and show that it worked. I had the battery at the time and I had to go outside, charge the battery up, and go through security again

Comment: I'd suggest you to take a busy lane. Then they will probably take less time to check these kind of things...

Comment: @Ollelo that's not a bad idea. I was unlucky last time because I got selected for random extra security... Which meant I had to go through every control possible