# Can I travel with a laptop without a functioning battery?

Tags: airports, australia, airport-security, electronic-items

In a few days' time, I will be going to Australia to further my studies. I have a laptop whose battery died a while back. It turns on with the power cord, but not with the battery. Is it a problem if I bring the laptop? I'm worried that they will ask me to turn the laptop on. My native country is Singapore btw.

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/86956/laptop-with-no-battery